# Display Three Cards Images - JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I'm working on my first JavaFX assignment. I have to randomly display 3 card images. Originally I had the cards in a separate folder but it gave me an error and all I could decipher from this new extremely large error was that something could not be found. I assumed it was the card images so I moved them into the same directory as the .java file. Normally I would just email my instructor but he is out of town till next week. Any help would be appreciated. I will include a screenshot of the exception output after the code block.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javafx.application.Application;
//import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
//import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
//import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Ch14DisplayThreeCards extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    ArrayList<String> cards = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
        cards.add(String.valueOf(i+1));

    java.util.Collections.shuffle(cards);

    ImageView viewCard1 = new ImageView(new Image(cards.get(0) + ".png"));
    ImageView viewCard2 = new ImageView(new Image(cards.get(1) + ".png"));
    ImageView viewCard3 = new ImageView(new Image(cards.get(2) + ".png"));

    HBox root = new HBox();

    root.getChildren().add(viewCard1);
    root.getChildren().add(viewCard2);
    root.getChildren().add(viewCard3);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 500);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Display 3 Random Cards");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}



}
```

Don't have enough rep to include an image so here is the screenshot of the errors: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiZpm.png

Comment: Make sure the file names are correct and their location. Try printing out the `cards` array and actually seeing what it contains

Comment: It's telling you that your URL to the images is empty and invalid. You should try specifying an absolute path to the images, and see if it works. If so, you know you're on the right track.

Comment: Also note that the `Image` constructor is expecting a URL, not a filesystem path. You might want to do `new File(cards.get(0)+".png").toURI().toString()`, or `getClass().getResource(cards.get(0)+".png").toExternalForm()`.

Comment: I did make a separate Java Project and copied the array code and debugged so I could see the values of the strings. Then tested building a string with the array value + ".png" and checked that new string's value. Everything looked correct. No extra spaces or anything like that.

Comment: @Alyssa try James_D 's advice. The stack trace is absolutely related to an invalid URL. Try moving the images to the root directory of your compiled code, and then use `new ImageView(new Image(new URI("/" + cards.get(0) + ".png").toURL())));`

Comment: @James_D Thank you so much. The second suggestion worked. If it's not to much to ask what exactly is it doing? You're first suggestion got rid of the error but just gave me a blank gui window (not sure why). Either way thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Image` constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html#Image-java.lang.String-) is expecting the specification of a URL, not a file system path.

The best way to do this is probably to get a URL from the class loader that loaded the current class, and then convert it to a `String`. You can get such a URL with

```
getClass().getResource(cards.get(0)+".png");
```

This essentially says "construct a URL that represents a resource loaded from the same place as you loaded this class". So if your file is in the same package as the class, it will work. If you are running from the file system (i.e. classes are loaded as files), then this will generate a `file://...` URL. If you are running the application bundled as a jar file, it will generate a `jar://...` URL. You can of course log the URL (or its `String` form: see below), and see what it is giving you. This is helpful for debugging errors like the one you are seeing.

To get the `String` form of the URL, call `toExternalForm()` on the URL. So your final code might look like:

```
ImageView viewCard1 = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResource(cards.get(0) + ".png").toExternalForm()));
ImageView viewCard2 = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResource(cards.get(1) + ".png").toExternalForm()));
ImageView viewCard3 = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResource(cards.get(2) + ".png").toExternalForm()));
```